# Vectorize the sum of outer products of coresponding columns of two matrices using Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, octave, product

Suppose I have two matrices `A` and `B` which are made up of column vectors as follows.

```
A = [a_1,a_2,...,a_N];
B = [b_1,b_2,...,b_N];
```

Is there any way to vectorize the calculation of the sum of outer products for every column in `A` with the corresponding column in B. Here is my non-vectorized solution.

```
S = zeros(size(A,1), size(B,1));
for n=1:N
    S = S + A(:,n)*B(:,n)';   % S = S + a_n * b_n'
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This is Matlab. Sorry, for some reason thought that this was a place for Matlab specific questions.

Comment: No problem. I am adding the tag for Matlab so people watching that tag can see your question.

Comment: isn't what you are doing just A * B'  ? Given that N = number of column vectors, your loop should give exactly A * B'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not clear on what N is, but I assume that N = number of column vectors - which means you are simply doing A * B'

```
A = rand(3,4);
B = rand(3,4);
N = size(A,2);
S = zeros(size(A,1), size(B,1));
for n=1:N
  S = S + A(:,n)*B(:,n)';   % S = S + a_n * b_n'
end
%Check that you are doing A*B'
S == A*B'
>> ans =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
```

Comment: No, A*B' is not the same as what I am trying to achieve. Note that in my case every the ith column in A is only ever multiplied by the ith column in B.

Comment: @Andrew how is it not? give me an example that proves it is not, I used the example in your answer and obtained the result almost 500 times faster.

Comment: I also thought "no, this can't be right" when implementing back propagation... but it was just the trick.