# MATLAB: vectorised backpropagation (no loop over training examples)

Tags: matlab, neural-network, octave

In MATLAB/Octave, how do I implement backpropagation without any loops over the training examples?

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/294938/162527) talks about the theory of parallelism, but how would this be implemented in actual Octave code?

Answer (score 0):

For me the final piece of the puzzle came from [computing sum of outer products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731361/vectorize-the-sum-of-outer-products-of-coresponding-columns-of-two-matrices-usin).

Here is what I came up with:

```
% X is a {# of training examples} x {# of features} matrix
% Y is a {# of training examples} x {# of output neurons} matrix
% Theta is a cell matrix containing Theta{1}...Theta{n}

% Number of training examples
m = size(X, 1);

% Get h(X) and z (non-activated output of all neurons in network)
[hX, z, activation] = predict(Theta, X);

% Get error of output layer
layers = 1 + length(Theta);
d{layers} = hX - Y;

% Propagate errors backwards through hidden layers
for layer = layers-1 : -1 : 2
  d{layer} = d{layer+1} * Theta{layer};
  d{layer} = d{layer}(:, 2:end); % Remove "error" for constant bias term
  d{layer} .*= sigmoidGradient(z{layer});
end

% Calculate Theta gradients
for l = 1:layers-1
  Theta_grad{l} = zeros(size(Theta{l}));

  % Sum of outer products
  Theta_grad{l} += d{l+1}' * [ones(m,1) activation{l}];

  % Add regularisation term
  Theta_grad{l}(:, 2:end) += lambda * Theta{l}(:, 2:end);
  Theta_grad{l} /= m;
end
```